# Feynman's Derivation for Principle of Least Action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

In the Feynman Lectures on Physics (Addison–Wesley, Reading, MA, 1964), Vol. II, Chap. 19, Feynman demonstrates how the principle of stationary action for one particle implies Newton's second law (or more precisely, that $m\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -V'(x)$). The online version can be found [here](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_19.html). Anyways, while doing so, he seems to disregard a lot of terms in the algebra because they are of "second order." For example, at one point he's evaluating the integral $$ { S = \int _{t_1} ^{t_2} \left[ \frac{m}{2} \left(\dfrac{d {x} }{dt} + \dfrac{d \eta}{dt}\right)^2 - V({x} + \eta) \right]}.$$

However, when he expands the square, he claims he can disregard the $\left(\frac{d \eta}{dt}\right)^2$ term, since it is of "second order," which I don't really understand. I understand the idea that we're letting $\eta$ go to zero (though it's still kind of confusing because $\eta$ is a function and not a variable), and since $\eta$ is going to zero, we can disregard any second order approximations with it because they will be much smaller than any first order approximations with $\eta$. However, just because $\eta$ is going to zero, that doesn't mean  $\frac{d \eta}{dt}$ is going to zero. In fact, $\frac{d \eta}{dt}$ could be as large as we please, so how are we allowed to just disregard $\left(\frac{d \eta}{dt}\right)^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using $\eta(t)$, $\eta(t_1)=\eta(t_2)=0$, replace $\eta(t)$ with $\epsilon \xi(t)$ where now $\xi(t)$ is fixed, and $\xi(t_1)=\xi(t_2)=0$. Then expand wrt $\epsilon$ and let $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

What is being evaluated is not the function $\eta$ itself, what is evaluated is how the value of the action responds to variation that is represented with $\eta$.

In the integral that you give Feynman gives only the linear terms. That means that the value of that integral is correct only when the variation is infinitesimally close to the true trajectory. And yes: that does mean that for all forms of the variation where (any part of) it is *more* than an infinitesimal distance away from the true trajectory the value of the integral is incorrect. The thing is: for the objective of the derivation that is of no consequence.

It is sufficient for that integral to be mathematically correct at the point were the variation is zero, that is the only spot where it matters.